# Is there a way to make tail output newlines?

Tags: macos, tail

When I do

```
tail -f $file
```

I see newlines as `\n`. For example:

```
permissions array(\n  0 => \n  stdClass::__set_state
```

Is there a way to make it turn into

```
permissions array(
  0 => 
    stdClass::__set_state
```

Comment: What OS are you on? Are you using an unusual version of `tail`?

Comment: @jjlin OSX, tag now added.